# Checking if a variable is of data type double

Tags: c#, casting, double

I need to check if a variable I have is of the data type `double`. This is what I tried:

```
try
{
    double price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Product price is not a valid price", "Product price error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return false;
}
```

I thought this would work, but obviously, I failed to realize if `txtPrice.Text` had anything other than a number in it, the `Convert` class will just parse it out.

How can I realiably check if a variable is a double?

Comment: "variable" is the wrong word. You're trying to determine if text can be converted to a floating-point value. If you were determining the type of a variable, you would use variable.GetType() == typeof(double)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use this:

```
double price;
bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price);
if(isDouble) {
  // double here
}
```

Comment: That's better, but it still lets it through if I enter "qwerty" as the price. It catches it if I leave it blank, however.

Comment: use the bool result returned by tryparse

Answer (score 12):

> How can I realiably check if a variable is a double?

You need to be clearer about what you're *really* trying to do here. I don't think you're asking what you think you're asking, and it's worth being aware of the differences in terminology.

If you've got a variable which is *declared* to be of type `double`, then it's definitely a `double`. If you've got a variable which is declared to be of type `object`, `ValueType` or one of the interfaces it supports, then you can use

```
if (value is double)
```

But it sounds like what you really want to know is whether a *string* value is *parseable* as a `double`. For that, you should use [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) - but you *also* need to think about what culture you're interested in. For example, would you view "15,5" as a valid `double`? European users might, but US users probably wouldn't. Do you want to allow thousands separators?

I would strongly advise you to use the overload which takes an `IFormatProvider` and use the appropriate culture. Even if the culture you're interested *is* the default, it's worth being explicit about that.

You probably want:

```
double result;
// For suitable values of text, style and culture...
bool valid = double.TryParse(text, style, culture, out result);
```

Then use the `valid` variable to determine whether or not it was actually parsed correctly. If `valid` is true, then the value of `result` is the parsed value. If `valid` is false, `result` will be 0.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`Double.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx):

```
double price;
if (Double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price))
{
    Console.WriteLine(price);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a double!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you try something like this -

```
  double doubleVar;
    if( typeof(doubleVar) == double ) {
        printf("doubleVar is of type double!");
    }
```

This can easily check if the variable is of a type double .

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use:

```
double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
```

?

With this you will a FormatException saying "Input string was not in a correct format." if the string value isn't a double, which looks to be roughly what you were doing manually anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use .GetType() to return the type of the variable if you are unsure what is being returned if a method is being called to generate the number. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(v=vs.71).aspx for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

- `double.ParseExact` or
- use Regex to check if it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

[Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

So if I get your question right, you mean you only want to allow numbers right?
If that's true, then maybe this will help you.

```
string Str = textBox1.Text.Trim();
double Num;
bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
if (isNum)
MessageBox.Show(Num.ToString());
else
MessageBox.Show("Invalid number");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `double.TryParse()` it will return `false` if it couldn't create a double.