# How to check if the value of string variable is double

Tags: c#, string, double, real-number

I am trying to check if the value of a string variable is double.

I have seen this existing question ([Checking if a variable is of data type double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823836/checking-if-a-variable-is-of-data-type-double)) and it's answers and they are great but I have a different question.

```
public static bool IsDouble(string ValueToTest) 
    {
            double Test;
            bool OutPut;
            OutPut = double.TryParse(ValueToTest, out Test);
            return OutPut;
    }
```

From my code above, when the ValueToTest is "-∞" the output I get in variable Test is "-Infinity" and the method returns true.

When the ValueToTest is "NaN" the output I get is "NaN".

Are they both "-∞" and "NaN" double values in C#?

Also is there a way to check for only real numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) and exclude infinity and NaN?

Comment: Yes, they are... See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double).

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks. How then can I test for only real numbers?

Comment: Just check if the double is either of the two (NaN or Infinity). Then return false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are valid values for `double`: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double).

Just update your method to include the checks on `NaN` and `Infinity`:

```
public static bool IsDoubleRealNumber(string valueToTest)
{
    if (double.TryParse(valueToTest, out double d) && !Double.IsNaN(d) && !Double.IsInfinity(d))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`"NaN"` and `"-∞"` are valid strings parseable to `double`. So you need to filter them out if you don't want them to be treated as valid `double` values:

```
public static bool IsValidDouble(string ValueToTest)
{
    return double.TryParse(ValueToTest, out double d) && 
           !(double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Double have infinity and inNan checks, hope this will get.

```
 if (Double.IsInfinity(SampleVar))
{
  //Put your  logic here.
}
if (Double.IsNaN(SampleVar))
{
  //Put your  logic here.
}
```